# How to make bitmap(set in src) compress?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio, bitmap

I wrote an universal custom ImageView , there are parts of code:

```
public class AvatarImageView extends ImageView {
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
  
Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
 // I want to make this bitmap compress

}
```

and then I can use this custom ImageView like this:

```
<CustomerView.AvatarImageView
                 android:layout_width="60dp"
                 android:layout_height="60dp"
                 android:src="@drawable/avatar"
                 />
```

It will lead to an oom error when I set more than 2 AvatarImageViews in my listview . 
I see a lot of developers make it in that way: [Google Training Loading Large Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html)

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resId, options);
```

**It needs to offer a resId . But I want to reuse this custom ImageView ,so I couldn't offer a certain id** .

Is there any good solutions ?
 Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thank you!